# malloc()ated string buffer gets corrupted in/right-before strcpy()?

Tags: c, string, memory, malloc, strcpy

So, I'm `malloc()`ating a variable, something like this in a function in C:

```
char * foo;
foo = (char *)malloc(32 * sizeof(char) +1);

// some irrelevant (to the variable) code

function2(&foo);
free(foo);
```

And then, I copy a string into `foo` in `function2()`:

```
void function2(char ** foo)
{
    // Some more (presumably) irrelevant code

    strcpy(*foo, "asdf");
}
```

This is part of a much bigger project (a compiler). I wasn't able to reproduce this problem in a standalone C program, but stripping many of the variable dependencies, the above code seems ok.

My problem is, that the call to `strcpy` causes a segfault 95% of the times (undefined behaviour the rest).

Following the execution with `gdb`, I found that, up to this moment I can `print foo` and see an empty string:

```
(gdb) s
1445        // line of code right before call to strcpy()
(gdb) print *foo 
$18 = 0x6064c0 ""
(gdb) s
1455        strcpy(*foo, "asdf");
(gdb)
```

However, right before `strcpy()` is called, `print *foo` gets me a `$19 = 0x2a00000002 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x2a00000002>` and right after, *most of the times*`strcpy()` will throw the SegFault, or the string will be corrupted and cause the next `strcpy()` to throw the SegFault. Corruption is also random, as sometimes the pointer address will be intact (with  gibberish characters), but sometimes `0x0`. The program may, occasionally, mess with other strings too, right at that point.

What causes that? Is *foo supposed to be freed before the call? Probably not. Could some other piece of code mess with its memory?

The strings seem to be properly allocated. I also tried with calloc(), allocating right before the `strcpy()` call, different buffer sizes, copying "\0"s and copying from other buffers.
Printing `*foo`, right after `strcpy()`, *sometimes* prints random gibberish, *sometimes* exactly what I expect it, and *sometimes* nothing at all.

**EDIT #1:**

I was only able to quantify it to this:

Removing the `strcpy()` call in `function2()`, I see on `gdb` that the `*foo` variable has an address and value ("" @ 0x606420), but as soon as the function call returns, the pointer in the main function, points to `0x0` and that makes the next call to `strcpy()` SegFault.

Trying to emulate the problematic `function2()` doesn't work. The code in `function2()`, while extensive, does not touch, at any moment, the parameter(after removing strcpy(), of course).

Comment: Please show a minimal compilable example of this. You're doing something wrong somewhere else, the bug is not in the code here. Also make sure you've included stdlib.h,

Comment: @nos I would. But I'd have to send you half the compiler. Eliminating ALL of `*foo`'s dependencies brings us to this code here. I'll try to add an Edit, with simpler code. stdlib.h is included, as well as string.h. The program compiles with no warnings with `-Wall`.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but note that you should NOT cast the return value of `malloc()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3488231

Comment: If you have a problem, please post a complete compilable sample that demonstrates the problem. One pointer and one function is not too much to ask. But your code is *"something like this"* and omits code that you think is "irrelevant" even though you don't know what the problem is.

Comment: (Irrelevant code) is corrupting the stack/heap. Compile with -O0 -g and use valgrind or similar runtime analyzer.

Comment: @user3125367 Interesting. I'll try that. I'll edit if I find anything.

Comment: Your bug is likely stack or heap corruption elsewhere in your code. 
On Linux, go run [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) using its memcheck tool. On Windows, you can use [AppVerifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find similar bugs.

Comment: @selbie Yes, it probably is. I used Valgrind's memcheck, fixed a couple of issues with some pointers, the problem is still there. Valgrind shows `Use of uninitialised data` and `invalid read of size 1` which are effects of the pointer = `0x0`, and then the SIGSEGV.
I'm not exactly familiar with valgrind. Is there any way I could find what is causing that pointer to equal 0x0?

Comment: If `valgrind` says you're reading through a zero pointer, aka NULL, then there are two main possibilities. (1) At the time when you make that call to your `function2()`, the value in `*foo` is a null pointer, and you need to look at the code between the `malloc()` and the call to work out what's going astray, or (2) the code inside `function2()` is causing the pointer to be nullified. Clearly, adding `fprintf(stderr, "-->> %s: *foo = %p\n", __func__, *foo);` would help you distinguish between (1) and (2). Or you can put a breakpoint on the function in the debugger and print the value on entry.

Comment: You can add more similar print operations between the point where you last find that `*foo` is not null and when it turns up as null.  Did the irrelevant code after the `malloc()` include a check that `malloc()` succeeded?  If not, you should add one, and handle failure appropriately.

Comment: I found what was wrong. While the code was good, I used an older version header file for some of the functions, were `function2()`s old prototype was without parameters, as opposed to it's definition. Found out because, `gcc` was silent with a `char * (32)` as a parameter instead of `char **`

Comment: @ShadoWalkeR Post your own answer and accept it to complete this post.

Comment: Empty arglist means default argument widths will be applied. Passed &foo and accepted char** are the same types. No char vs int, int vs long or similar incompatibilities. Are you sure old-style declaration was an actual issue?

Comment: @user3125367  I thought the same about OP's solution and would like to see OP post the solution.